# Google Analytics for Advanced Data Extraction

Tags: php, laravel, google-analytics

I am planning to use the FREE Google Analytics as the engine for analytic for an ecommerce website. Is it possible for me to do the advanced data extraction from Google Analytics for the following task?

1. Every merchants will have their own analytic statistic on the website control panel to view how is their store page performing, which product people view the most, and etc detail statistic info.
2. Web system will able to use Google Analytics to have deep understanding about each individual customer like what product they view the most, how frequently they visit and etc. Then, using the info to provide most relevant suggestion to each individual customer.

Is this possible to be done with Google Analytics or I really need to have my own analytic system & store all the data myself?

Comment: You can extract data from Google Analytics using the [Analytics Reporting API V4](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/) along with the [PHP client Library](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client). As for your specific use case and the metrics you might wish to track, [analytics.js](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/) fairly full featured, but the underlying [measurement protocol](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/) can be done from any application.